# is the Parity Mnemonic my private key - or is it my private key-passphrase combination?

Tags: wallets, parity, parity-wallet

Essentially what I'm asking is - can I recover my wallet using just the mnemonic from the Parity wallet, or would I ALSO need my original passphrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put - It is a friendly seed to generate your private key(s).

The mnemonic is a phrase that can be memorized to generate your private key. These are based on HD Wallet keys detailed here https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet

Comment: Sure, but do I need my passphrase to recover the keys afterwards, or is it strictly my unencrypted key alone? I am asking specifically in the case of Parity wallet.

Comment: You do not need the passphrase. If you have the mnemonic you can generate keys with just that.